# Initialize root password on MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I'm installing MySQL 5.7 on a new Ubuntu 16.04 server. Since my installation uses Ansible, no root password is defined at installation time, and I set it up later with the mysql_user role in ansible, but the root password stays empty.

I therefore tried to run the command directly on MySQL, without Ansible, but I get the same behaviour : no error on the alter user command but password is not set.

My server configuration :

- OS :

  - Distributor ID: Ubuntu
  - Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
  - Release:        16.04
  - Codename:       xenial
- Database : MySQL 5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1

Step to reproduce :

- Install mysql-server-5.7 package without providing a root password.
- Connect to mysql from the system root account

And then run the mysql commands :

```
mysql> select authentication_string from user where host='localhost' and user='root';
+-----------------------+
| authentication_string |
+-----------------------+
|                       |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> alter user root@localhost identified by 'mypassword';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> select authentication_string from user where host='localhost' and user='root';                                                                                                                              
+-----------------------+
| authentication_string |
+-----------------------+
|                       |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

However, running the same command with a hashed value works :

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH 'mysql_native_password' AS '*D7B8FEAED940F8F2A0055864C0A59782B4BCED02';

mysql> select authentication_string from user where host='localhost' and user='root';
+-------------------------------------------+
| authentication_string                     |
+-------------------------------------------+
| *D7B8FEAED940F8F2A0055864C0A59782B4BCED02 |
+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

And then, I can change the password with the original request :

```
mysql> alter user root@localhost identified by 'mypassword';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> select authentication_string from user where host='localhost' and user='root';
+-------------------------------------------+
| authentication_string                     |
+-------------------------------------------+
| *FABE5482D5AADF36D028AC443D117BE1180B9725 |
+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Why does the "unhashed" version not work the first time ? Am I missing something or is this a bug in this version of MySQL ?